# Can two equally sized systems at different temperatures have different entropies?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Basically, it means that can a system have a higher "maximum entropic" state than another?
Assuming  both systems have equal number of molecules. All of molecules of both systems are hovering at a constant temperature (say x degree kelvin for one and x-20 degree kelvin for the other)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. If you define entropy as
$$
S=-\text{tr}\left\{\rho \ln(\rho)\right\}
$$
with the canonical density matrix
$$
\rho = \frac{e^{-\beta\cdot\hat{H}}}{\text{tr}\left\{e^{-\beta\cdot\hat{H}}\right\}}
$$
and $\beta = \frac{1}{k_bT}$, you see that while the hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ for your $n$ molecules in a box does not change, the entropy does, since it depends on the temperature $T$.

Comment: Thank you! What if n*x > m*(x+20), with n>m? Where n is number of molecules in the lower temperature system and m is the number of molecules in the higher temperature system

Answer (score 1):

In standard thermodynamics entropy is defined by
$$
dS = \frac{dQ_\mathrm{rev}}{T}
$$
that is the change in entropy is given by the (reversible) heat added to the system divided by the temperature. Heating the system can obviously change the temperature, so systems with different temperatures having different entropies follows more or less immediately from the definition.

Comment: Thank you! What if n*x > m*(x+20), with n>m? Where n is number of molecules in the lower temperature system and m is the number of molecules in the higher temperature system